# MIPS Prime number factors

Tags: mips, primes

I am trying to write a program in MIPS, where you enter a number and it tells you whether it is prime or not, and if it is prime it also gives all the prime numbers up to it. Ex: n = 11, and it will print: "11 is prime, and so are 2, 3, 5, 7, 11". I am not sure how to create the loop to check if numbers before the input are prime and to print or skip over them.

```
.data 
    string1: .asciiz  "Please enter an integer: "
    string2: .asciiz  "Input is a prime number" 
    string3: .asciiz  "Input is not a prime number" 
    string4: .asciiz  "   "
    string5: .asciiz  "Prime numbers up to the input are: " 

.text 

main: 

    # Print string 1 
    la $a0, string1 
    li $v0, 4 
    syscall 
    
    # Take input from user 
    li $v0, 5 
    syscall 
    
    # Store input in temp register 
    move $t8, $v0 
    
    # Initial value for processing
    li $t9, 2 
    
    # Corner cases 
    blt $t8, 1, NotPrime 
    beq $t8, 1, NotPrime
    beq $t8, 2, Prime
    
    loopPrime: 
        beq $t9, $t8, Prime  # Branch to prime when input equals initial value 
        div $t8, $t9  # Divide input by numbers in range 
        mfhi $t1 # Move division remainder to t1
        beq $t1, $0, NotPrime  # If remainder equals 0, the input is not prime number 
        addi $t9, $t9, 1 # Increment initial value by 1 
        b loopPrime
        
Prime: 
    li $v0, 4 
    la $a0, string2 
    syscall 
    
    li $v0, 4 
    la $a0, string4 
    syscall 
    
    li $v0, 4 
    la $a0, string5 
    syscall 
    
    # Initial value2 for processing 
    li $t7, 2 
    
    b loopfactor2
    
    b Exit

loopfactor1: 
    addi $t7, $t7,1
    b loopfactor2

loopfactor2: 
    beq $t9, $t7, Print 
    div $t7, $t9
    mfhi $t1 
    beq $t1, $0, Skip 
    addi $t9, $t9, 1
    blt $t7, $t8 loopfactor1
    
    b Exit 
    

Print: 

li $v0, 4 
move $a0, $t7
syscall

Skip: 

addi $t7, $t7,1 
b loopfactor2
            
NotPrime: 
    li $v0, 4 
    la $a0, string3 
    syscall 
    b Exit 

Exit: 
    li $v0, 10 
    syscall
```

Comment: A simple algorithm for checking primality on a range of numbers is the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes#Pseudocode)

Comment: It looks like you have found working code that doesn't do what you want.  Getting that code to do what you want will take programming, not a question post at this website.  You need an algorithm for getting it to do what you want, and you don't have to create your algorithm in assembly: it is easier to write it in C, and then when working, translate that to assembly.  This separates the concerns of algorithm from those of assembly language, simplifying the job.  It's much easier to write assembly when you know what needs to be done in advance.

Comment: Write/work out the loop in C and then translate to assembly.  If you have problems with translating a loop from C into assembly,  you can search/ask about that, showing the C code and your translation attempt.  You'll need nested loops, an outer to iterate over numbers and an inner to detect primes.

Comment: Sieve seems overkill--I'd just write a brute force loop for starters, then try to optimize if that's part of the deliverables. Post seems pretty broad--what's the specific issue/question here? Thanks.